# Ruby on Rails queue question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message-queue

I have been trying to figure out a solution but nothing has really presented itself to work. I am building a system that sends out emails (among other things), and I have been trying to figure out a way to have the queuing of messages work. I would like to provide the user a (somewhat) accurate count of the messages sent so far. I was thinking of having the user facing page, and then another page that would start the sending process and continually output (no like a refresh, just kind of a real-time output) and then parse that and make the information more user-friendly. I'm open to any suggestions on how I could do this, and thanks for any ideas ahead of time!

Comment: You really should phrase the question as the title.  We know its a question about ruby on rails, actually ask the question in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721297/message-queues-in-ruby-on-rails) about message queues in rails.

Essentially, choose a messaging queue and interogate it for the status once in a while with a jquery ajax timer or something.

Comment: Thanks Sam! Do you know how I would go about getting the status?

Comment: @Alex, it depends on the framework you use ... they all do it differently make sure you read the article by topfunky in the linked question