# Queuing to avoid race condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, rspec

The scenario I'm facing is as follows:

Each user can click a button and enter a queue, called "waiting room". Once there are n users in this queue, this n users should be grouped together and ejected from this queue.

The implementation I have:

I used a non-persistent `model` containing a ruby set to serve the purpose. `user_id` can be added to the set. It works fine when users enter the queue in sequence.

The possible problem:

If the website is under heavy load such as 1000 (> n) users are entering the queue at the same time, I'm afraid bad things will happen (like some users get tied to multiple groups and ejected multiple times). I don't know if Rails has some internal mechanism to prevent this or it depends on the data structure of my choice. **I want something like a event queue that web browsers have**. That is, events can come in at the same time but only get handled one by one. How do I ensure that?

Testing:

How do I write RSpec tests to simulate the heavy load scenario?

Comment: Do you have a singular persistent background process that can handle this or are you depending on your database to do the grouping? If it's a database solution you're looking for you can use transactions to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1815876/1249891

Comment: @tadman
I didn't write any code to spawn a background process. The logic goes into a ActionCable `channel`. If number of in-queue users reaches n, it will call the corrsponding model to create and store a record that represent the group of users to database. Do you have any suggested examples similar to this and solutions that I can read on?

Comment: Avoiding race conditions usually means adding a queue and forcing them through a single process, or using a lock to prevent duplication. Either solution should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronized Method for concurrency in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090731/synchronized-method-for-concurrency-in-ruby)

Comment: look at the example on the [Mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Mutex.html#method-i-synchronize) docs

Comment: Thanks guys. Both tadman and @maxpleaner comments made snese to me. I'd be appreciated if someone can add some info about how to reproduce the scenario in RSpec.

Comment: @XiaohongDeng kinda hard to reproduce race conditions on demand, but you could try testing with a lot of runs

Comment: @XiaohongDeng this could help -> https://github.com/2rba/Race-Conditions-Rspec-HowTo/blob/f078c6ab27/spec/models/key_value_spec.rb. They wrote a helper to help reproduce race conditions. Also, a video of it(albeit in Russian), is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZG198z4e7I (the code is in English)